# What rear shock will fit my Scott spark 2009?

Tags: suspension

Can anyone tell me what rear shock will fit my 2009 Scott Spark 60?

I brought the bike second hand with the wrong rear shock, because of the current shock the geometry of the bike is incorrect.

It is meant to have a Manitou Radium RL, I cannot find measurements or specification or a place to buy this shock.

Any help will be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

From your bike [manual](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.scott-sports.com/manuals/09bike/2009_manual_u_spark_gb_web.pdf):

Piston stroke: 37mm

Shock (Eye to Eye): 165mm